# @MockBeans example use

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a controller class that makes use of several services. I write a test for that controller like:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = PurchaseController.class, secure = false)
public class PurchaseControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private ShoppingService shoppingService;

    @MockBean
    private ShopRepository shopRepository;

    @MockBean
    private SomeOtherRepository someOtherRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

// ... some tests goes here
```

Thing is, that there tend to be many of those mocks, thus many lines of code. I know this may be a sign of a code smell, but that's not my point now.

I noticed that there is also a `@MockBeans` annotation that has `@Target(ElementType.TYPE)`. So I thought I could try:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = PurchaseController.class, secure = false)
@MockBeans(value = {ShoppingService.class, ShopRepository.class})
public class PurchaseControllerTest {
```

but it doesn't event compile.

My question is: how we could use `@MockBeans` annotation? Is it applicable to my case?

Comment: you can do same thing with `@MockBean`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`@MockBeans` it's just a repeatable annotation for multiply of `@MockBean` s. If you need to reuse this mocked bean you can put in on a class / config class. But you need to use  `@Autowired` for services that you what  to mock . So in your case it should be :

```
.....
@MockBeans({@MockBean(ShoppingService.class), @MockBean(ShopRepository.class)})
public class PurchaseControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  ShoppingService shoppingService;
  @Autowired
  ShopRepository shopRepository;
.....
}
```

Main idea of `@MockBeans` it's just repeating `@MockBean` in one place. For me it might be useful only for some configuration / common class that you can reuse.

`@MockBean` - create a mock , `@Autowired` - is autowired bean from context , in your case ,it mark/create bean as mocked then mocked bean will be injected in your autowired field.

So if you have a lot of autowired fields with `@MockBeans`(or multiply `@MockBean`) you can configure is it a  mock or not in one place (in `@MockBeans` for class level) and you don't need change `@Autowired` to `@Mock` in you test class (like in you case if you remove `@MockBeans` all autowired beans that are not mocked will be autowired as beans from context , and if you undo removing you will work  in mocked beans (that you configured inside this annotation) ) .

If you want to avoid a lot of dependency inside one class you can extract all dependency into some parent class , but as java doesn't support multiply inheritance for class it's not always might help.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like not much profit then. I can list all my mocks in class level, but I have to autowire them anyway...

Answer (score 8):

The shortest variant in your case is `@MockBean` which support multiple values of required classes of mocks

```
@MockBean({ShoppingService.class, ShopRepository.class})
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But what should I annotate it with? `@MockBean({A.class, B.class}) private XXX xxx;` What is XXX then?

Comment: in this case annotation should be on class level.

Answer (score 3):

Javadoc says it's used as

> Container annotation that aggregates several {@link MockBean} annotations.

So you can write

```
@MockBeans({@MockBean(ShoppingService.class), @MockBean(ShopRepository.class)})
public class PurchaseControllerTest {
```

`@Autowire ShoppingService` works here

Or

> Can also
>    be used in conjunction with Java 8's support for *repeatable annotations*

```
@MockBean(ShoppingService.class)
@MockBean(ShopRepository.class)
public class PurchaseControllerTest {
```

Java 8 enables *repeatable annotations*, and for compatibility reasons, repeating annotations are stored in a container annotation `@MockBeans` that is automatically generated by the Java compiler. In order for the compiler to do this, you need 2 things:

- Repeatable `@Repeatable(MockBeans.class)` Annotation Type `@MockBean`
- Containing Annotation Type `@MockBeans`